# neo4j cypher loop to return two matches for each collection element

Tags: loops, collections, neo4j, cypher

I want to return for each keyword in collection two most related users to keyword. Query below works fine with only one keyword.

```
WITH
   'meeting' AS keyword
MATCH 
    (k:keywords)<-[r1:RELATED]-(u:users)
WHERE 
    k.keyword = keyword
    AND NOT u:deactivated
    AND NOT u.userid1 = 'administrator'
    AND NOT k:deleted
    AND r1.datedeleted = 0
    AND r1.datedeleted IS NOT NULL 
WITH
    DISTINCT u.userid1 AS user,
    r1.weight AS rel
ORDER BY 
    rel DESC
LIMIT 2
RETURN
    user
LIMIT 20
```

How to make a loop to the same as query above for each collection element? (e.g. collection below)

```
WITH 
['meeting', 'new', 'tool', 'training', 'it', 'process', 'server'] AS kw_my_channels
```

More precisely, I need a cypher loop to do my query for each collection element (keywords) returned from a query done before (here manually defined as kw_my_channels). 
The issue is to implement a "for" loop, which execute a MATCH for every collection element. In this case the elements are keywords which are related to users. The relation has weights (relevance of the keyword for this user). This weights show how often a keyword was used by the user (count).  For every keyword, two users with the highest weights should be found.

An example output should look like:

```
Keyword | Users         | Weight
-------------------------------
meeting | user1, user2  | 80, 75
new     | user1, user4  | 40, 34
tool    | user5, user8  | 33, 22
```

Comment: In the future you'll be able to use UNWIND for this: `UNWIND [....] as keyword MATCH ....`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
MATCH (k:keywords)<-[r1:RELATED]-(u:users)
WHERE k.keyword IN ['meeting', 'new', 'tool', 'training', 'it', 'process', 'server']
AND ...
```

Etc.

**UPDATE**

Could you do something like this?

```
WITH
    'meeting' AS keyword
MATCH 
    (k:keywords)<-[r1:RELATED]-(u:users)
WHERE 
    k.keyword = keyword
    AND NOT u:deactivated
    AND NOT u.userid1 = 'administrator'
    AND NOT k:deleted
    AND r1.datedeleted = 0
    AND r1.datedeleted IS NOT NULL 
WITH
    DISTINCT u.userid1 AS user,
    r1.weight AS rel
ORDER BY 
    u.userid1 DESC, rel DESC
RETURN
    user
LIMIT <# of distinct users * 2>
```

Note the removal of the "LIMIT 2", the changing of the "ORDER BY", and the "LIMIT" change at the bottom.  Of course, this assumes that each keyword has at least two distinct users attached to it.  That might be a non-starter for you.

Are you able to programmatically/dynamically insert a value for <# of distinct users * 2> into the query?  It'd be nice if you could use something like "LIMIT COUNT(user) * 2" but that's invalid in Cypher.

Unfortunately, I don't think Cypher currently allows you to use FOREACH for anything but mutating operations.

Hopefully this is of some use to you.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but if I want 20 users in all (at the end) I get only 20 users related to first one, or two, depends on keyword count. I want to recommend users where always 2 users are related to one keyword and so on.  
It is also questionable, does it performs better to call first cipher statement for each keyword from PHP? I would like to compare it...

Comment: I'm sorry; I really don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps you can provide a diagram or some ASCII art depicting some expected results. Or, better yet, a sample console at console.neo4j.org.

Comment: So, tried to explain it more precisely (see above), hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now.